# Set text inside UIEdgeInsets?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to insert a text inside the area which one surrounded by `UIEdgeInsets` in `UITextView`.

Take a look at the following image

[image]

Here '1'(surrounded by border for easier understanding) --> The text which one I want to insert inside the `UIEdgeInsets`.

Here 'one' is the content inside `UITextView`.

Can I do it? If it is, give me an example.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ <3

Comment: put image or elaborate your question :)

Comment: Please take a look now.

@IronManGill

Comment: I still dont get it ... what do u want to do ?

Comment: I want to create a list element like in HTML.

User can't edit the number of an list.

The same thing, i want to do it here. If i insert the number inside the UIEdgeInsets, user can't edit the number of list.That's all.

@IronManGill